# .htaccess redirection issues with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I am running a website on apache and the problem i am facing is below .

The actual link looks like this : 
**www.domain.com/my-account/profile-view.php?id=1018428**

where **id** is the user id of the user .

Now my .htaccess looks like this :

```
RewriteRule ^my-account/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ my-account/profile-view.php?id=$1
```

Basically i want the URL to be rewritten like this :

www.domain.com/my-account/15/Craig

I've done different permutations to the above htaccess line and none seem to work . Any help would be appreciated .

P.S : My htaccess is working fine and is being read by the server .

Comment: What does `15` have to do with `1018428`?

Comment: What does "none seem to work" actually mean? What result _do_ you get? An error message? Which? Nothing happens? A white screen? Does the universe implode?

Comment: it gets redirected to an error page . Be it 15 or 1018428 , doesnt matter , they are just the ids

Comment: And _what_ error page? What message? Don't have us drag all details out of you! It is in _your_ interest to provide these details!

Comment: A 404 error page which says page not found .

Comment: Then most likely your rewrite rule does not get applied. I suggest you enable rewrite logging and take a look at what exactly is going on inside your rewrite engine. That should show the issue. Also I could imagine that you placed the `.htaccess` style file at the wrong location in the file system or that its interpretation is not enabled at all. Sorry, but nothing we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you

```
RewriteRule ^my-account/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ my-account/profile-view.php?id=$1&name=$2 [nc,l]
```

You need two variables since you have two regex in your url:
 - ([0-9]+) for the id
 - ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) for the username

The nc flag means non-case-sensitive (so Craig will also match craig)
the l flag means "last", when rule is validated, stop processing the htaccess rules below that point

Comment: That is not what the OP asks. The question clearly shows the structure of the desired internal target URL. No "name" parameter in there.

Comment: @arkascha yes its missing from this example